# ExpressJS External Links Break

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-applications

I have a NodeJS App running on C9.io (which is why my port looks odd). My website works on c9 and on my webserver. However, my external link on the second app.get doesn't work. It adds the link to the end of the current url when I want it to be only that URL. 
For example www.mysite.com > www.mysite.com/www.externalwebsite.org.
I want it to do: www.mysite.com > www.externalwebsite.org.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/", function(req,res){
    res.render("singlepage");
});

app.get("/www.externalwebsite.org", function(req,res){
    res.redirect("www.externalwebsite.org");
});

app.listen (process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("ServerStarted");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redirect to a complete url (add `http://`):

```
app.get("/www.externalwebsite.org", function(req,res){
    res.redirect("http://www.externalwebsite.org");
});
```